# Размер icon в ActionBar

Tags: java, android, xml, android-sdk

Как изменить(уменшить) размер `item`, который является 'imageButton' в `ActionBar`, так как иконка очень широкая, на превью XML разметки все в норме, но при запуске, широкая очень.

Работает так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`XML` menu_main.xml:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/item1"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:title="Меню"
    android:icon="@drawable/menu_circle">
</item>
```

превью: [image: превью]

`XML` custon_icon.xml : 
Здесь же я описываю кнопку, которую в дальнейшем анимирую.

```
<ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton"
    android:contentDescription="Меню"
    android:src="@drawable/menu_circle"
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:clickable="false" />
```

Превью: [image: превью]

rotation.xml - код, который описывает вращение элемента:

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillEnabled="true"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="500"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/overshoot"/>
```

И сам Java код:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    menu.findItem(R.id.item1).setActionView(iv);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Часть кода для инициализации кнопки:
    iv = (ImageView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_icon, null);
    iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

```
        Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotate);
        iv.startAnimation(rotation);

        if (mDrawerLayout.isShown()) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        } else {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Если вы [посмотрите в гайдлайны](https://material.google.com/style/icons.html#icons-system-icons), то увидите, что размер иконок для ActionBar (Tollbar) фиксированный и составляет 24dp.

Answer (score 0):

В файле menu_main.xml вы задаете значение высоты элемента "match_parent". Соответственно она и растягивается на всю возможную высоту. Ограничьте ее размер как в файле custon_icon.xml. Если размер будет большой, уменьшите его. Ну и в принципе рассмотрите возможность убрать явное задание размеров высоты и ширины item в меню. Андроид прекрасно справляется с этим.